# How can I zoom in on a point in d3.js, manually, without using d3.behavior.zoom()?

Tags: d3.js, graph, zooming

Since I've already implemented panning and axis-dragging myself, I'd like to also manually implement zoom functionality. The code I have so far is:

```
const zoomXY = () => {
    const intensity = 0.035

    // how to implement the correct translation(s) before/after scaling below?
    let tX = tempXScale.invert(mousePoint[0] - plotWidth / 2),
        tY = tempYScale.invert(mousePoint[1] - plotHeight / 2)

    let wheelSign = Math.sign(wheelDelta),
        eX = xDomain[1] - xDomain[0],
        eY = yDomain[1] - yDomain[0],
        tempXMin = xDomain[0] + wheelSign * (eX * intensity),
        tempXMax = xDomain[1] - wheelSign * (eX * intensity),
        tempYMin = yDomain[0] + wheelSign * (eY * intensity),
        tempYMax = yDomain[1] - wheelSign * (eY * intensity)

    tempXDomain = [(tempXMin > 0.001 ? tempXMin : 0.001), tempXMax]
    tempYDomain = [tempYMin, tempYMax]

    tempXScale.domain(tempXDomain)
    tempYScale.domain(tempYDomain)

    redrawX()
    redrawY()
    redrawLines()
}

const mouseWheelPlot = (e) => {
    d3.select('.focus').style('display', 'none')

    mousePoint = d3.clientPoint(e.target, e)
    wheelDelta = e.deltaY
    zoomXY()

    onSetXDomain(tempXDomain)
    onSetYDomain(tempYDomain)
}
```

As it stands, this is very "hack" zooming functionality, since it only arbitrarily exapands/contracts the x and y scales and then redraws the plot elements. I want to be able to 'zoom in on a point' in d3, similar to this functionality discussed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42741960/how-do-you-zoom-into-a-specific-point-no-canvas).

Answer (score 1):

I figured it out - here's an implementation in case anyone needs it going forward.

```
const zoomXY = () => {
  const mX = mousePoint[0],
        mY = mousePoint[1],
        sX = tempXScale.invert(mX),
        sY = tempYScale.invert(mY)

  /*
   ** Scale
   */
  const wheelSign = Math.sign(wheelDelta),
        percentage = 0.025

  let eX = xDomain[1] - xDomain[0],
      eY = yDomain[1] - yDomain[0]

  tempXDomain = [
    xDomain[0] + wheelSign * (eX * percentage),
    xDomain[1] - wheelSign * (eX * percentage)
  ]

  tempYDomain = [
    yDomain[0] + wheelSign * (eY * percentage),
    yDomain[1] - wheelSign * (eY * percentage)
  ]

  tempXScale.domain(tempXDomain)
  tempYScale.domain(tempYDomain)

  /*
   ** Translate
   */
  let dX = sX - tempXScale.invert(mX),
      dY = sY - tempYScale.invert(mY)

  tempXDomain = [
    tempXDomain[0] + dX > 0.001 ? tempXDomain[0] + dX : 0.001,
    tempXDomain[1] + dX
  ]

  tempYDomain = [
    tempYDomain[0] + dY,
    tempYDomain[1] + dY
  ]

  tempXScale.domain(tempXDomain)
  tempYScale.domain(tempYDomain)

  redrawX()
  redrawY()
  redrawLines()
}

const mouseWheelPlot = (e) => {
  d3.select('.focus').style('display', 'none')

  mousePoint = d3.clientPoint(e.target, e)
  wheelDelta = e.deltaY
  zoomXY()

  onSetXDomain(tempXDomain)
  onSetYDomain(tempYDomain)
}
```